# VBA Object Required When Getting Row From Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract a single row from a range object within a function. The range is declared as a variant, and then set to a range within my sheet. I want to be able to pick out a specific row, so I tried to call `.Rows(indexfrom, indexto)`, but I get the error `Object Required`. I've tried setting `compareRow` instead of just declaring it, but that doesn't seem to change anything. I believe it's caused because `callLogRange` only exists as a reference to the range object. If this is the case, how can I use the reference to get the row from the range? Alternatively, am I just missing something that enables you to get the row?

Thank you.

```
Dim callLogRange As Variant
callLogRange = (Sheets("CallLog").Range("B2:L" & lastRow))

Dim compareRow As Variant
compareRow = callLogRange.Rows(thisRow, thisRow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dim them as `Ranges` and use `Set`:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim callLogRange As Range, thisRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 13

    Set callLogRange = Sheets("CallLog").Range("B2:L" & lastRow)

    thisRow = 5
    Dim compareRow As Range
    Set compareRow = callLogRange.Rows(thisRow)

    MsgBox compareRow.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

- the cells are in the **sixth** row of the worksheet which is the **fifth** row of the primary range
- if you instantiate `compareRow` without the `Set`, you are actually creating an internal *VBA* **array** rather than a `Range`.

Comment: ++ That was fast :D

Comment: Is there a way to quickly index the `callLogRange` as a `Range`? When I set it as a Variant, I can simply use `callLogRange(1,1)` to get the value at row=1,col=1.

Comment: Note that the `Set` assignment would still fail if the surrounding parentheses wouldn't have been dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the parentheses.

This:

```
callLogRange = (Sheets("CallLog").Range("B2:L" & lastRow))
```

Is evaluating `Sheets("CallLog").Range("B2:L" & lastRow)` as a **value**. Remove the parentheses and you'll be assigning a 2D array instead.

Or `Set` the reference and you'll be assigning a `Range` object reference, as in [Gary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899545/1188513)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for the reference too. I'm also considering Gary's answer, but I'm not sure which one would be "more correct".

Comment: Gary's answer is better, because it works off a `Range` object - I only addressed the specific "Object Required" error here. It's always better to work with objects and explicit types, than with a `Variant`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure. Very appreciative for the help. And the parenthesis evaluating issue will be something I keep in mind from now on.